# A non well formed numeric value encountered in ...on Line 171

Tags: php, php-5.6

We keep getting the above error.  Have tried adding a $start above 171 but same result.  Here is the code :

```
/**
 * Get all of the months since a certain date
 */
public static function getMonthsSinceDate($start) {

    $key_month = date('MY', $start);   (note this is Line 171)
    $key = 'months_since_' . $key_month;
    $months = CodonCache::read($key);

    if ($months === false) {
        if (!is_numeric($start)) {
            $start = strtotime($start);
        }

        $end = date('Ym');

        do {
            # Get the months
            $month = date('M Y', $start);
            $months[$month] = $start; # Set the timestamp
            $start = strtotime('+1 month +1 day', strtotime($month));

            # Convert to YYYYMM to compare
            $check = intval(date('Ym', $start));

        } while ($check <= $end);

        CodonCache::write($key, $months, 'long');
    }

    return $months;
}

/**
```

Comment: `var_dump($start);` __What__ do you see?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you are calling the function getMonthsSinceDate(); you are accidentally passing it something non numeric. It could be subtle like a number wrapped in quotes which would become a string, i.e

```
getMonthsSinceDate('111111')
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `date()` expects to be given a date in an integer UNIX timestamp. If you are trying to pass a human-readable date as a string it will throw an error.

If you are, convert it to a timestamp using `strtotime()`, like this:

`$start = strtotime( $start );`

Comment: Here is the code setting "getmonths" - public static function getMonthsSinceStart() {
        
        $months_list = CodonCache::read('months_since_start');

        if ($months_list === false) {
            $date = self::GetStartDate();

            if (!$date) {
                $startdate = time();
            } else  {
                $startdate = $date->submitdate;
            }

            $months_list = self::getMonthsSinceDate($startdate);
            CodonCache::write('months_since_start', $months_list, 'long');
        }

        return $months_list;
    }

Comment: That doesn't help much since there are 3 other functions there getting the dates - `CodonCache::read('months_since_start')`, `self::GetStartDate()` & `$date->submitdate`. We can't see from the code how they are returning the dates, so you need to confirm for yourself the format that the dates are being returned in. Finally, it's best to update your original question with this extra code as it's a little hard to read in a comment!!